# Compiz flickers when an external monitor is plugged in, doesn't stop until reboot or log out/in

Tags: 15.04

I have a serious issue with Compiz (not only on Unity): When I plug in an external screen (projector, for example), the screen flickers (I'd have to record a video to demonstrate just how), and becomes unusable.

The only way to fix it is to restart or (if possible) log out and log back in (with the monitor removed). The worst part is that CTRL+ALT+Function keys become impossible to use once this happens, so a hard reboot is sometimes the only option.

I am using Intel Graphics (Sandy Bridge), so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it. I did not have this problem on 14.10.

Comment: @Mandx this seems to be fixed now, as I'm able to use Compiz with my external monitor. I have not tested it with the projector since the problem went away.

Comment: Encountered similar issues on 18.04 MATE/Compiz on an Intel 4th Gen Haswell, but not a 7th Gen Kaby Lake. Adjusting the OpenGL plugin settings in CompizConfig Settings Manager has reduced the issue, but I'm not sure if it has solved it yet. More discussion: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=174522&p=899349

Answer (score 0):

If this still applies to you, can you try this two things the check if we have the same issue?

- While logged out (login screen) can you plug/unplug the external screen and everything works as expected?
- While logged in (your desktop) plug in (or unplug) the external screen, now the screen is unusable, hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 (this switches to a virtual terminal), login and run `killall compiz`, then hit Ctrl+Alt+F7 (this switches back to the visual terminal, the desktop). You should see the screen flicker a couple of time and become usable again, with the external screen enabled (if you plug it in in the first step)

Comment: It's a different issue. I wouldn't even be able to switch to a virtual terminal.